# What is the series solution to $y''-3x^2y'-6xy=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

In attempting this, I got that the answer was
$$y(x) = a_0 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{(3n)!!!}x^{3n} + a_1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{(3n+1)!!!}x^{3n+1} + a_2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{(3n+2)!!!}x^{3n+2}$$
but I can't find any way to verify that this is indeed correct.

Comment: Can you show us your work on solving this second-order linear ordinary differential equation?

Comment: Here's my updated final solution in closed form: $y(x) = a_0 \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{3^{k+1}}{(3k+3)!!!}x^{4k} + a_1 \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{3^k}{(3k+1)!!!}x^{4k+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle y = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n x^n$.  Then
\begin{align}
  y' &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} na_n x^{n-1},\\[0.3cm]
  y''  &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}.
\end{align}

Substituting these series into the original equation gives us

\begin{align}
  0 &= y'' - 3x^2y - 6xy\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} - 3x^2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_nx^{n-1} - 6x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_nx^n\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}3na_nx^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 6a_nx^{n+1}
\end{align}

Let's modify these series so we can combine them into one series to easily determine the coefficients.  Note that we will most likely need to have some "stray" terms sitting outside of the summation notation when we do this.  This is fine.
\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} &= 0 + 0 + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n
\end{align}
The second equality above is obtained by re-indexing the series.  Specifically, we replaced $n$ with $n+2$.
\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}3na_nx^{n+1} &= 0 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}3na_nx^{n+1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}3(n-1)a_{n-1}x^n
\end{align}
The second equality above comes from replacing $n$ with $n-1$.  The same with this equality below:
\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 6a_nx^{n+1} &= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 6a_{n-1}x^n
\end{align}
So then we have:
\begin{align}
  0 &= y'' - 3x^2y - 6xy\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} - 3x^2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_nx^{n-1} - 6x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_nx^n\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}3na_nx^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 6a_nx^{n+1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n - \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}3(n-1)a_{n-1}x^n - \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 6a_{n-1}x^n\\[0.3cm]
    &= (2)(1)a_2 + (3)(2)a_3x + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n - \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}3(n-1)a_{n-1}x^n - \left[6a_0x + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} 6a_{n-1}x^n\right]\\[0.3cm]
    &= 2a_2 + 6(a_3-a_0)x + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - 3(n-1)a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-1}\right]x^n
\end{align}

Since the only constant term is $2a_2$, we must have $a_2 = 0$.  Similarly, we must have $a_0 = a_3$.  Looking at the coefficients on the series, we see that we must have
$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - 3(n-1)a_{n-1}-6a_{n-1} = 0$$
as well.  So then
\begin{align}
  0 &= (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - 3(n-1)a_{n-1}-6a_{n-1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - [3(n-1)+6]a_{n-1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - 3(n+1)a_{n-1}\\[0.3cm]
  3a_{n-1} &= (n+2)a_{n+2}\\[0.3cm]
  3a_n &= (n+3)a_{n+3}
\end{align}
The last equality above comes from replacing $n$ with $n+1$.  So then we finally obtain
$$ a_{n+3} = \frac{3}{n+3}a_n.$$

Since we have a second-order ODE, we expect $a_0$ and $a_1$ to be the arbitrary constants by which all the other coefficients are determined.  And we already know that $a_2 = 0$.  So for the first few values of $n$, we have
\begin{align}
  a_3 &= \frac{3}{0+3}a_0 = \frac{3}{3}a_0\\[0.3cm]
  a_4 &= \frac{3}{1+3}a_1 = \frac{3}{4}a_1\\[0.3cm]
  a_5 &= \frac{3}{2+3}a_2 = 0\\[0.3cm]
  a_6 &= \frac{3}{3+3}a_3 = \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{3} a_0\\[0.3cm]
  a_7 &= \frac{3}{4+3}a_4 = \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{4} a_1\\[0.3cm]
  a_8 &= \frac{3}{5+3}a_5 = 0\\[0.3cm]
  a_9 &= \frac{3}{6+3}a_6 = \frac{3}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{3}a_0\\[0.3cm]
  a_{10} &= \frac{3}{7+3}a_7 = \frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{4} a_1\\[0.3cm]
  a_{11} &= \frac{3}{8+3}a_8 = 0\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

So we have $a_0, a_1$ arbitrary and $a_2 = 0$, and for $n > 0$ we have
\begin{align}
  a_{3n} &= \frac{3^n}{(3n)!!!}a_0\\[0.3cm]
  a_{3n+1} &= \frac{3^n}{(3n+1)!!!}a_1\\[0.3cm]
  a_{3n+2} &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: I think you made an error in your simplification to the recursion formula. Instead, shouldn't it be $0 = (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} - 3(n+1) a_{n-1}$ which results in $a_{n+2}=\frac{3(n+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_{n-1} \Leftrightarrow a_{n+3}=\frac{3}{n+3}a_n$

Comment: and thank you for your reply! I appreciate the assistance. I should've typed up how I got my answer but I couldn't remember how to format in LaTeX because I've been writing math in Microsoft Word for so long now...

Comment: No problem.  Yes, you're right, should've been $-3(n+1)a_{n+1}$.  Got the sign wrong on the 6.  It's fixed now, thanks.

Comment: awesome, I fixed my original answer too and got what you got! Thanks! Btw, I also used the triple factorial. It seems that some sources define it differently than what I would assume. Is it not common practice to define $n!!!=n\times(n-3)\times\cdots$ ?

Comment: That's how I would define it, but I had a Calc II professor many years ago who taught us about double factorial and triple factorial, etc.  Since then I've encountered very few people who know what that is.